# Can we use stream in flutter for assigning data to Class variables (not mapping data into widget)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

This is my UerModel Class, and i have to load data into class variables. And also want to auto fetch each time on any update.  that's why i use Streams, but it does not allow, as I have to return a widget.

```
class UserModel {
      late String name;
      late String dob;
    
      UserModel({required String id}) {
          StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('movies')
                  .doc('star-wars')
                  .snapshots(),
    
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                
                name = snapshot.data!['name'];
                dod = snapshot.data!['dob'];
               // return 
              });
      }
}
```

Comment: check `Stream.listen` or `Stream.forEach` methods

Comment: @pskink thanks for your response, but no one work in this case ):

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('movies').doc('star-wars').snapshots().listen(print);` does not show anything?

Comment: it shows in my app, as according to my database. but I want to auto check for data. for example, i fuser update some field, so that data update automatically as it work in widget under `StreamBuilder` .

Comment: this is what `Stream.listen` method is for: it listens for any new event from that stream - simply use it like `listen((data) { do_something_with_data });`